# Point Set Topology: Countably Infinite

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to work a problem and I am having trouble wrapping  my mind about what $\textbf{X-U being countably infinite mean}$?. Here X is our given set and U subset of X such that X-U is countble or is all of X. This says, X-U is finite or countably infinite or all of X right?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Must be the hour...

Comment: X is a set, and $T_c$ is the coollection of aall subsets U of X s.t X-U is either countablr or is all of X. But the definition of countable is finite or countabley infinte. So the statement now becomes X-U is countably infinite or finite ot all of X. What does the first mean?

Comment: So you are unsure of what "countably infinite" means? Is that the source of your confusion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here $X-U$ denotes complement. So you're given the topology of countable complement, or the cocountable topology, that is $$\tau=\{U\subseteq X:X-U\text{ is countably infinite }\}\cup\{\varnothing\}$$

That  $X-U$ is countably infinite means it is not finite, and is equipotent with the set of natural numbers, i.e. we may exhibit $X-U$ as a list $\{x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots\}$

Comment: why is the empty set included?

Comment: is it because its finite?

Comment: @Faraad Topologies always include the empty set.

Comment: T is just a coollection. We want to show it is a topology. So you dont know that the empty set is included yet.

Comment: So we get the empty set since thee emmpty set is a subset of all sets, so by definition of T this allows the empty set to exist right?

Comment: @Faraad A subset, but not an **element**. And as I wrote above, we *define* the cocountable topology to include the empty set.

Answer (score 0):

this problem to show that your set is a topology you need to satisfy the condition of the set, and the definition of the topology.

we know that if U is equal to X, then the empty set is included.  if U is the empty set then the complement includes the empty set.  this satisfies the first condition of a topology.

then let U  equal a non empty arbitrary unions of U contained in the set U.  then after using de morgans laws,  we have that the set of intersections of (X-U_{i}) is contained in the parent set X-U  which is countable. thus the subset is countable.  then you jusst need to show the last part